# Drag and Drop plots and other available features of Core-Plot?

Tags: ios, core-plot

i am new to `core-plot` frame work, i have few doubts about the feature of this frame work. May be my question very simple or unwanted, but still i am posting here for my clarification.

1. Its possible to drag and drop plot in core-plot framework.
2. Can i achieve smooth scrolling (like: UIScrollView) in `core-plot`?
3. If my graph size is beyond screen size means, how i can handle to scroll the graph to see fully?

If Its possible means kindly guide me to which `Class` or `API` provide this features, or any other things i have to follow. Thank you in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes.

Set the `allowsUserInteraction` to `YES` for each plot space you want to respond to touch scrolling and pinch zoom events. Set `allowPinchScaling` to `NO` on the hosting view to keep the scrolling behavior and disable pinch gestures.

The `xRange` and `yRange` of the plot space determine the visible are of the plot area. Any plot data outside these ranges will be clipped and invisible. The plot ranges can be changed by the user (via scrolling and/or zooming) or directly in code by the app.

Be sure to look at the example apps included with Core Plot. Many of them include scrolling graphs.

Comment: what about each plot drag and drop?

Comment: The question is tagged iOS. What do you mean by drag and drop? iOS doesn't support drag and drop the way that term is usually used on the Mac.

Comment: if i create a plot, at run time can i touch a plot and reposition the plot to some other place with in the same plots pace?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "scrolling" in my answer above.